# Creating an Assistant. How can I loop it to go back to the top to listen for its name? Just asking about how I could loop the program

Tags: python

This is a part of the program that detects any commands and I tried to do a `while True`...

```
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:

        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Assistant Processing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
        print("User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(exception handler removed to shorten code here)

    return query


if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

    # This Function will clean any
    # command before execution of this python file
    clear()
    wishMe()
    usrname()

    query = takeCommand().lower()
    while True:
        if assistname in query:
            voice_activation = True
            query = takeCommand().lower()
            # All the commands said by user will be
            # stored here in 'query' and will be
           (There are commands here)
```

Then, at the very bottom of all the commands, I have this...

```
if not assistname in query:
    voice_activation = False
```

`assistname` is a variable that I identified as the name for the assistant. The `while True` didnt work and I am wondering how I could program it so that it loops back to the top, waiting for me to say the name over and over until I actually say it and then once the command is carried through, it waits again.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you wanted?

```
    clear()
    wishMe()
    usrname()

    while True:
        if assistname in takeCommand().lower():
            voice_activation = True
            query = takeCommand().lower()
            # All the commands said by user will be
            # stored here in 'query' and will be
           .
           .
           .
           break #if that's what you want

        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I know it was a simple question but it really helped a lot!